# How to force Swift to wait the previous code is finished?

Tags: swift

I just began learning Swift, I am working with an API behind, the problem is that : **Swift don't wait my function finish therefore my last function appears like no code was done before**.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

// Classes
class User {

    init(data: Any) {
        self.sex = JSON(data)["sex"].string!
        print(self.sex)
    }

    var id: Int = 1
    var online: Bool = false
    var picture: String = ""
    var sex: String = "Male"
}

// Fonctions
func getBackground(_ apiURL: String, completion : @escaping(_ :Any) -> Void) {
    // Requête API avec Alamofire + SwiftyJSON
    AF.request(apiURL, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let jsonData = JSON(value)
            completion(jsonData["results"])
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    }
}

// Requête de connexion
getBackground("https://x..me", completion: { response in
    let user = User(data: response)
})

print(String(user.id) + ": " + String(user.online!))
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8GHB.png)

I have this error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'user'", I guess that Swift don't get the fact that User was defined previously

All my work works perfectly with my API, the "self.sex" is set and showed when I build the code.
But I'm still "locked" like I can't do nothing after this code because Swift don't want to wait.

I tried the function async and sync but then, all my next code has to be under a function...

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Swift don't get the fact that User was defined previously"* - you need to read up on variable scope. `user` only exists inside the curly braces it is declared in.

Comment: Because I am sleeping my code, to wait the data is loading, but it changes nothing. Is there another way to do my function asynchronously and let wait my next code ?

Comment: The whole point of an asynchronous call is *not* to wait. Embrace it, don't try to work around it.

Comment: i will look around, thank you

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to wait.

Put the `print` line – and the code which proceeds the user – in the *completion* closure

```
getBackground("https://a.clet.me", completion: { response in
    let user = User(data: response)
    print(String(user.id) + ": " + String(user.online!))
})
```

The error `Use of unresolved identifier 'user'` occurs because the local variable `user` is only visible inside the scope (`{}`) of its declaration.

Comment: I have a lot of work to do after, I am stuck in this function for all the stuff I have to do after ?

Comment: Then put the *lot of work* into an extra function and call that in the closure. This is the usual workflow for asynchronous data processing

Comment: Maybe there is another way to put the data of my API inside a variable?

Comment: Of course, you can use a global variable, but it doesn't affect the asynchronous behavior of the closure.

Answer (score 2):

So, this problem is all about variables life cycle.

```
// This happens first

getBackground("https://a.clet.me", completion: { response in
    let user = User(data: response)

    // This happens third, once the request has completed.

    // user exists here.
    // Only after this moment you should handle anything related to the user
})

// This happens second

// user DOESN'T exist here, swift will move on
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can i put the class outside this function? That is what I am wondering...

Comment: Yes. And just like you used an `@escaping` closure on `getBackground`, you have to do the same in order to pass variables on asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Because what you're trying to do is to access a variable outside it's scope. And that is exactly why we use `@escaping`.

Comment: So there is no another way to execute my code? Swift can’t wait my function finish before continue execution of code ?

Comment: You can, but the fact that it's asynchronous says that you don't know when the user data will be available, that is why it's good practice to use it only inside the completion scope. You can call another function inside of it, passing the user as a parameter.

Comment: Or maybe, is there a way to put my data inside a variable, that will avoid me to being stuck in this function for my last code?

Comment: What is making you "stuck" is the fact that the network request takes a while. You need to wait the request and response time.

Comment: at "move on", you can keep doing any other task.